# Setting a bail out proxy based on HOST header

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, rewrite

We have set up a proxy during our migration phase and saw that people try to abuse it.
It is correctly configured and forward only to our application server but these trials charge our main server.
Idea is to use the proxy to bail out requests containing "http://" in the host header to decrease our application server load.

I added the two first line to implement the bail out.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://.* [NC]
    RewriteRule .* / [F,L]

    ProxyPass / http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
```

But it does not work I as expect. The proxy still works instead of returning 401.

An alternative would be to make a

```
    RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

But I don't know if it will do the trick.